# Updating version of a Julia without reinstalling packages from previous version

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

Recently new version (0.4) of the Julia was rolled out.
I would like to install it, since I noticed some bugs in my current 0.3.11 version. But after installing 0.4 I realized my packages from 0.3.11 are not in 0.4.

It would be very tedious to reinstall these packages again (and repeating this process for every version update going forward) given the speed of the package manager, so I was wondering if there is a workaround for this?

Comment: Did you try copy "~\\.julia\\v0.3" to "~\\.julia\\v0.4"? you can find your right path using `Pkg.dir()`

Comment: I did, but when I say `Pkg.status()` they are not displayed

Comment: If you are using `IJulia`, after install new version of `Julia`, and before using `IJulia` make sure to install it with `Pkg.add("IJulia")` from julia REPL.

Comment: Also check -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30555225/how-to-upgrade-julia-to-a-new-release

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can also simplify the process by copying your Project.toml from your ~/.julia/environments/v1.x to your ~/.julia/environments/v1.y and doing a Pkg update. That will install all the same packages you had before.

Comment: Is this outdated in version 1.0?

Comment: It's replaced by copying your `Project.toml` from your `~/.julia/environments/v1.x` to your `~/.julia/environments/v1.y`.